# User authorization in DB2

Tags: db2

I am using win Vista, and I am trying to backup some Database under DB2.

I am logged in using the `Administrator` user, and whenever I try to issue the backup command in the "command line processor", I get the following message:

`SQL1092N  "ADMINISTRATOR" does not have the authority to perform the requested command.  SQLSTATE=00000`

BTW, I have created a username/password pair (db2admin) while installing the DB2 server.
So, Will this problem will be get solved if I use the `db2admin` user? And how to connect to the server (local server BTW) using the `db2admin` user ?

Comment: Yes, looks like it expects the db2admin.

Comment: So, The question is, How to switch to db2admin?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem recently and this seemed to do the job:

1. Attach to your [local] node.  (the value of your DB2INSTANCE environ variable, mine was 'DB2'):

   ```
   attach to DB2 user db2admin using mypassword;
   ```
2. If this isn't enough (it didn't seem to be with me), you can also specify the user and password with backup and restore commands:

   ```
   restore database mydbname user db2admin using mypassword from C:\BACKUPS taken at 20100823132457;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Or manually create the db2admin user with a password on Windows. But I'm not sure if that's the correct option here.